# Configure Keyboard on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-layout

I’m trying to permanently set the keyboard to [abnt2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195107.aspx) on Arch Linux. Every session that start I have to type:

```
# setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -model abnt2
```

I searched on Google but the solutions below didn't worked for me:

1. Run the command:

   ```
   # loadkeys br-abnt2
   ```
2. Edit the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf`. This file did not existed, so I created it:

   ```
   Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "evdev keyboard catchall"
   MatchIsKeyboard "on"
   MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event"
   Driver "evdev"
   Option "XkbLayout" "br"
   Option "XkbVariant" "abnt2"
   EndSection
   ```
3. Create and edit the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-keyboard-layout.conf` as follows:

   ```
   Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "Keyboard Defaults"
   MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
   Option "XkbLayout" "br"
   EndSection
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As per this answer on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99090), you should try adding the full `setxkbmap` to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`.

Typically each user should only have `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` so check which one you have set on your system and then open it up like this; I’m using `~/.bash_profile` as an example and using `nano` as an editor for example:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

And then just add that `setxkbmap` to that file:

```
setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -model abnt2
```

Then logout of the terminal, log back in again and all should be good.

Comment: I've tryed edit the ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile and add #setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br but didn't worked.

Comment: ```.xsessionrc``` file should be the right place to put the ```setxkbmap``` command.